# Как использовать aiogram для связи с дискордом

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram, discord

Есть телеграм бот на aiogram. Суть в том, что хендлер должен отправить команду в дискорд боту midjorney и получить ответ. Подскажите кейс. С discord вообще не сталкивался никогда. Нужно разворачивать бота дискорд? Код должен быть асинхронным.